# is it possible to save timepicker's data and show them in the next time the app starts?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, save, timepicker

i am working on a project which includes user to put any time chosen by the time picker, but when i exit the app and open it again the chosen time is gone.

is it possible to save timepicker data and use them when the app starts next time? thank you

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener;

public class AndroidTimeActivity extends Activity {

    TimePicker myTimePicker;
    Button buttonstartSetDialog;
    Button buttonCancelAlarm;
    TextView textAlarmPrompt;

    private TimePicker timePicker;
    CheckBox optRepeat;
    SharedPreferences sPref;
    final static int RQS_1 = 1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        timePicker = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.picker);
        optRepeat = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.optrepeat);
        textAlarmPrompt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.alarmprompt);
        buttonstartSetDialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startSetDialog);
        TimePicker dp =  (TimePicker)this.findViewById(R.id.picker);
        dp.setCurrentHour(1);  
        //  
        dp.setCurrentMinute(01);  



        buttonstartSetDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Calendar calSet = Calendar.getInstance();

                calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
                calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
                calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);



                setAlarm(calSet, optRepeat.isChecked());
            }});

        buttonCancelAlarm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        buttonCancelAlarm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                cancelAlarm();
            }});


    }


    private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal, boolean repeat){

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);



        if(repeat){
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                    targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), 
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                    pendingIntent);

            textAlarmPrompt.setText(
                    "\n\n***\n"
                    + "Alarm is set@ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
                    + "Repeat\n"
                    + "***\n");
        }else{
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                    targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), 
                    pendingIntent);

            textAlarmPrompt.setText(
                    "\n\n***\n"
                    + "Alarm is set@ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
                    + "One shot\n"
                    + "***\n");
        }

    }




    private void cancelAlarm(){

        textAlarmPrompt.setText(
                "\n\n***\n"
                + "Alarm Cancelled! \n"
                + "***\n");

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);






    timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new OnTimeChangedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "onTimeChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }});    

    }
}
```

EDIT: thanks to kruczjak i found the solution:

i used this code in the onclick to save the value to the preferences when the button is clicked

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit(); editor.putInt("hour", timePicker.getCurrentHour()); editor.putInt("minute", timePicker.getCurrentMinute()); editor.commit();
```

and used this code to open the last saved value from the preferences

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); timePicker.setCurrentHour(prefs.getInt("hour", 1)); timePicker.setCurrentMinute(prefs.getInt("minute", 01));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to  override `onStop()` method in activity and put there code to save somewhere (database, file or even shared preferences) selected time from `timePicker`.
Then read it and apply to `timePicker` in `onCreate()`

See this article about activity lifecycle for more http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: thank you! which method is easier to use to save the data? and what should i write to get the timepicker's values??

Comment: The simplest solution is to use SharedPreferences (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). Use `getCurrentHour()` and `getCurrentMinute()` on timePicker to get time. Later `setCurrentHour()` and `setCurrentMinute()` to set it back

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your save time button

```
//Pref To save time picker  
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putInt("hour", YourTimePicker.getCurrentHour());
editor.putInt("minute", YourTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());
editor.commit();
```

and call this method in your onCreate() of time picker activity

```
public void  loadTimer(TimePicker timepicker) {
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
timepicker.setCurrentHour(prefs.getInt("hour", 1));
timepicker.setCurrentMinute(prefs.getInt("minute", 01));
}
```

you will write

```
loadTimer(YourTimePicker);
```